# Hide Equals and ReferenceEquals

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I am creating an internal class to provide a construct for the Contract pattern.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace DCS2000.Common35.Core
{
  public class Assertion
  {
    public static void Ensure(bool test)
    {
        if (!test)
        {
            throw new PreconditionException("Precondition test failed");
        }
    }

    public static void Ensure(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new PreconditionException("Precondition null object failed");
        }
    }

    public static void Require(bool test)
    {
        if (!test)
        {
            throw new PostconditionException("Postcondition test failed");
        }
    }

    public static void Require(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new PostconditionException("Postcondition null object failed");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When a developer goes to use this they will see these as options in Intellisense:

- Ensure
- Equals
- ReferenceEquals
- Require

This is confusing and I am wondering if there is a way to hide Equals and ReferenceEquals.

NOTE:  I have already tried this, but it did not work for me:

```
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        throw new Exception("Assertion does not implement Equals, use Ensure or Require");
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new bool ReferenceEquals(object objA, object objB)
    {
        throw new Exception("Assertion does not implement ReferenceEquals, use Ensure or Require");
    }
```

This will hide the members if the developer has appropriate VS settings set, and will immediately notify, alas during run-time, the developer that they are inappropriately using Equals or ReferenceEquals, should they inadvertently use it in the code base.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you. I am finding it very helpful to find un-used methods in my most commonly used objects--particular if it uses a fluent interface.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Matti's answer, `EditorBrowsableState.Never` depends on the user's Visual Studio settings under Options, Text Editor, C#, General.

It only takes effect if the user has 'Hide advanced members' turned on. Visual Studio defaults to showing all members.

Comment: And the assembly which uses this cannot be loaded in the solution--you must reference the compiled DLL.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest, I think anybody who calls themselves a .NET developer should be used to having those methods around and ignoring them when not needed.

<del>If you really want to hide them, and if they're both overridable (I forget if `ReferenceEquals` is because I've never used it), you could override them as `private override`.</del>

Okay, that doesn't work. Now that I looked at it, `private override` makes no sense, `protected override` isn't quite allowed either and `private new` and `protected new` make new methods while the base class method is still accessible. I don't think you can hide them with access modifiers at all.

And it seems the whole thing was about static methods anyways. Gee, I really failed this one.

Comment: private override?  I could have sworn you *cannot* change the protection level on an override.

Comment: @Matti Equals is a virtual method and cannot be private.

Comment: @Tim: private new does not remove the Equals method from the interface. You're still calling the object's one.

Comment: The question is about the static version of Equals(), so the discussion about override is superfluous.

Comment: @Matti you should've stopped after the first sentence, which is totally correct :)

Comment: @Rex: Well, it's too late now. Would be lame to delete this after so many comments